# std::exp(-100.0f) == NaN?

Tags: c++, gcc, floating-point, g++, nan

g++ version (`5.4.0`) returns `NaN` for `std::exp` with floats smaller than roughly 87.

However the [docs to `std::exp`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/exp)
suggest, that it approaches `0` for small numbers:

> If the argument is -∞, +0 is returned

Is this a bug in the implementation of the standard library, or what am I missing?

The effect can be [reproduced](https://ideone.com/gBOrdL) like this:

```
#include <cmath>
#include <fenv.h>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    feenableexcept(FE_ALL_EXCEPT & ~FE_INEXACT);
    for (float x = 30; x > -1000; --x)
    {
        float y = std::exp(x);
        std::cout << x << "\t\t" << y << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
30              1.06865e+13
29              3.93133e+12
28              1.44626e+12
27              5.32048e+11
...
-84             3.3057e-37
-85             1.2161e-37
-86             4.47378e-38
-87             1.64581e-38
Floating point exception
```

Comment: [Cannot reproduce](https://wandbox.org/permlink/JBTFHz53xIMZImvE).

Comment: The feexp that triggers in your example would probably be some underflow exception, btw. That doesn't produce NaN, though, but subnormal numbers first and 0 later.

Comment: If you used the `double` overload it would have resulted in underflow after -708. Or -708.4 for IEEE-compatible `double` to be precise.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You specify `FE_UNDERFLOW` *the result of the earlier floating-point operation was subnormal with a loss of precision* (one of bit flags of `FE_ALL_EXCEPT`). The minimum value not equal to zero that can be represent by `float` is `1e-38`. After `x` reaches `-88`, you get the floating point exception while the result is `6.0546e-39` that is less than `1e-38`. It is not `NaN`, you tuned raise of the exception with the instruction `feenableexcept(FE_ALL_EXCEPT & ~FE_INEXACT)`.

If you remove the bit flag `FE_UNDERFLOW` your loop will output zeros (or small not zero values depending on a platform).

Comment: If the minimum value of float is `1.17549e-38`, how the `cout` function can display `6.0546e-39` ?

Comment: @MatthieuH Please show the example when cout can display float value 6.0546e-39.